# How to delete mysql database data from table, using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my PHP code, I can't get it to delete some data inside my MySQL database. I have tried some different things but it just won't work.

What iv'e tried: Deleting $productId, switched $producId to 1, 2, 3 and 4.

```
if (isset($_POST['remove_product'])) {
  $productId = 4

  $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = '.$productId.'";
  $stmt = mysqli_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: products.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
  } else {
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
  }
}
```

I would like if it could delete the data from the MySQL table, so if someone could come with a solution, thanks : )

Thanks!

Comment: When you say: won't work; what is it that doesn't work? Do you get an error message? Did you try issuing the delete statement directly in the mysql console? Is there even a row with id=4 in table products? Do you get the redirect to your error page? Then you should output [`mysqli_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: @yunzen Yes, there is an id=4 in the products table, when i try reloading the site i get this error message:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Webshop\products.php on line 17

Comment: Why didn't you include this error message in your question? Which one is line 17?

Comment: @yunzen $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = '.$productId.'"; is line 17 : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong functions to initialise, prepare and execute your statement. You should be using [`mysqli_stmt_init`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php), [`mysqli_stmt_prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) and [`mysqli_stmt_execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) instead. Also, since you are preparing a statement, you should take advantage of that to avoid SQL injection. Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['remove_product'])) {
  $productId = 4;

  $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ?";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: products.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
  }
  else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $productId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking a semicolon

```
$productId = 4
--------------^
```

Use

```
$productId = 4;
```

You have some issues with quotation marks:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = '.$productId.'";  
-------^--------------------------------^------------^^
```

It should say:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = " . $productId;
```

Also you are not using prepared statements in the right way

```
if (isset($_POST['remove_product'])) {
  $productId = 4;

  $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ?";
  if (!$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql)) {
    header("Location: products.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
  } else {
    $stmt->bind_params("i", $productId);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
}
```

Comment: Now i got it to work! Thank you all for your help ;)

Comment: If you think your question is answered, please accept the correct answer by clicking on the gray tickmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntactic mistakes in your code. Use mysqli-query to execute the the query. it is used frequently

```
if (isset($_POST['remove_product'])) {
  $productId = 4;

  $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ".$productId;
  $stmt = mysqli_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_query($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: products.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
  } else {
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
  }
}
```

try this once